# Is there a module for adding field types for latitude, longitude, compas coordinates, etc?

Tags: 7, theming

Either my google searching skills are low, or there is no such module for D7. I want to create a content type where a user can add his position on the sea: latitude, longitude, knots, heading (000°) and other coordinates. Do you know any module that does this?

Comment: Yes, there is. And it is easy to find. Search for location and geolocation keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) module allows you to store such data:

> Latitude and Longitude Supports entering data as both Decimal Degrees
>   (122.340932) and Degrees-Minutes-Seconds (-123° 49' 55.2" W). The
>   Degrees-Minutes-Seconds input is very tolerant of inconsistent input.
>
> Bouding Box Four textfields where lat / lon can be entered
>
> Well Known Text (WKT) A textarea for direct WKT input
>
> Draw on an OpenLayers Map Allows drawing of Points, Lines, Polygons
>   and Bouding Boxes
>
> HTML5 Geolocation Transparently asks the browser for the user's
>   current location. Works great on Chrome and smartphones with GPS.

You can encode data from another field using the [Geocoder](https://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module as well.

Comment: Can i make the fields look like [ ]° [ ]' [ ]" [ ], where those boxes are dropdowns ? for now i just get two textfield named lat/long

Comment: If you want to customize the display of field values, you could use Views (rewrite results) to add formatting.  If you want to provide a dropdown, you will have to write custom code to provide the options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Gmap module](https://drupal.org/project/gmap) along with [location module](https://drupal.org/project/location).

For more details you could go through the README.txt of these modules.